# C# COM object does not leave the memory

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I have 10 threads, each thread create a new instance of my object. Call 2 methods of this object and the cyclic life of the thread ends, the problem is that it remains in memory.

With that one hours eventually occurring one out of memory.

I have the following code:

```
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        new Thread(Thread_).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

void Thread_()
{
    spdNFeX _spdNFeX = new spdNFeX();
    try
    {
        String[] Chave = (String[])Chaves.ToArray(typeof(string));

        _spdNFeX.LoadConfig("");
        Random Rand = new Random();
        _spdNFeX.DiretorioLog = "C:\\Users\\Joao\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\TesteNFe\\TesteNFe\\bin\\Debug\\" + Convert.ToString(Rand.Next(1, 999) + "\\");

        for (int i = 0; i < Chave.Length; i++)
        {
            _spdNFeX.ConsultarNF(Chave[i]);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    finally {
        _spdNFeX = null;
    }

}
```

I performed the following tests, but without success.

Test 1

```
finally {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_spdNFeX);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

Test 2

```
finally {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_spdNFeX);
        _spdNFeX = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    }
```

Test 3

```
public class ComDisposer : IDisposable
{
    private List<Object> _comObjs;

    public ComDisposer()
    {
        _comObjs = new List<Object>();
    }

    ~ComDisposer()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public T Add<T>(T o)
    {
        if (o != null && o.GetType().IsCOMObject)
            _comObjs.Add(o);
        return o;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            for (int i = _comObjs.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_comObjs[i]);
            _comObjs.Clear();
        }
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}        

void Thread_()
{
    using (ComDisposer cd = new ComDisposer())
    {
        spdNFeX _spdNFeX = cd.Add(new spdNFeX());
        try
        {
            String[] Chave = (String[])Chaves.ToArray(typeof(string));

            _spdNFeX.LoadConfig("");
            Random Rand = cd.Add(new Random());
            _spdNFeX.DiretorioLog = "C:\\Users\\Joao\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\TesteNFe\\TesteNFe\\bin\\Debug\\" + Convert.ToString(Rand.Next(1, 999) + "\\");

            for (int i = 0; i < Chave.Length; i++)
            {
                _spdNFeX.ConsultarNF(Chave[i]);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whatever spdNFeX is, I would try calling `Dispose` on it before nulling it out if it is a COM object.

Comment: How could I do this? Previously had tried using this IDisposable interface, but without success.

Comment: You can't, COM objects are not disposable.  Ignore that comment.  Use a memory profiler to gather facts.  And consider the possibility of a deadlocked finalizer thread.

Comment: @HansPassant We're both right. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/7f43cb01-3296-4926-9973-4ec7de245ad0/disposing-com-objects on how to dispose COM memory

Comment: Hmya, that cargo cult never ends.

Comment: If `FinalReleaseComObject` doesn't seem to help I'd suspect the COM object itself is leaking memory and use a memory profiler.

Comment: Please check my new tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`.

Comment: That is rarely the correct answer and often will introduce more bugs.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Assuming you don't use the object after release it works just fine.  It just forces the reference count to 0.